# Is there a channel feature for Android push notifications on iphone?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am using flutter to create a cross-platform app for android and iOS.
I am having trouble with the push notification setting functionality due to the large difference between the two operating systems.

Android classifies notifications into channels and allows the user to toggle whether or not audio is present on each channel, or whether or not the notification itself is present,
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/channels

iOS has no concept of channels and only allows the user to toggle the appearance and presence or absence of all notifications in the app.

If you want to use Android's channel feature,
Do you accept the fact that iOS has no channel functionality, which degrades it so that you can only turn on/off the entire notification?
Or do I have to go through the trouble of creating a screen equivalent to Android's notification settings?